# UIDeviceRGBColor getRed:green:blue:alpha - unrecognized selector, not due to memory management

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uicolor, unrecognized-selector

I solved my problem by using `CGColorGetComponents`, but I would like to understand exactly what was the reason.

I was doing the following with an instance of `UIColor *firstColour` :

```
[firstColour getRed:&r green:&g blue:&b alpha:nil];
```

This was working perfectly fine on simulator. Then I tested it on my device, and got this error :

*UIDeviceRGBColor getRed:green:blue:alpha unrecognized selector sent to instance*

After some research on the Internet I found that `UIColor` is actually replaced by subclasses, like `UIDeviceRGBColor`. Fine, but shouldn't subclasses work just like `UIColor` and accept (at least) the same methods ?

I enabled Zombie but apparently this wasn't a memory management issue, like most people say on forums. And I can't find documentation for `UIDeviceRGBColor` so I don't know how it is supposed to behave. Does someone know why it happened, and above all, if this is likely to happen again with another method ?

Thank you.

Comment: The selector you are calling on the object is a class/static method not the object specific method. It returns the object of UIColor type. Here you are calling the message on firstColour of UIColor type.

Comment: To support older devices you can use [uicolor-utilities](https://github.com/ars/uicolor-utilities). Though i'm not sure how it's licensed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`getRed:green:blue:alpha:` method in UIColor is available starting iOS 5.0. Most likely the problem is that your device has older OS version where that method is not available.

On older OS you'll probably have to retrieve color components from underlying `CGColorRef` structure using `CGColorGetComponents`/`CGColorGetNumberOfComponents` functions

Comment: Wow, 2 hours searching for such a simple answer... Well, thank you, this was indeed probably the problem.